# How to check in C if the entered input is a number and nothing else

Tags: c, integer

I was just wondering I can't figure out how to write a function that will check in my program for user input and make sure if it's a number. So far I have this but for some reason it doesn't work...

When I input letters for example it prints out "Entered input is not a number" couple of times and then it jumps down to the else printf statement.

Here is the code I have so far (ps: this program is supposed to take 3 triangle side from user a, b, c and then calculate if it's a triangle inequality or not).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXINPUT 100

int main()
{
    
    int num;
    int a, b, c, s;
    char input[MAXINPUT] = "";
    int length,i;
  

    printf("Enter three side of a triangle:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    
    /*scanf("%s", input);
    length = strlen (input);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (!isdigit(input[i])){

            printf("Entered input is not a number\n");
        }*/


    s = (a + b);

    if (s > c) {
        printf("This is Triangle inequality\n");
    }
       else
    {
        printf("This is not a Triangle inequality\n");
    }     

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You ***check the return*** of `scanf()` and make sure it equals the number of conversions specified... (you must validate the return of each and every user-input function used to know whether the input succeeded or failed) e.g. `if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: Why are you using scanf twice? Why you need `input`, it's not used later on. Then you don't check if scanf for a, b, c has been successful.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the response it helped. I just got another question after this. How can I make sure that after it checks if the user input is integer and if it's not, to jump back to ask the user to enter a number again. (right now my code even if it fails prints out the error but then it continues to the last printf: printf("This is not a Triangle inequality\n");```

Comment: What *is* the 4th input `scanf("%s", input)`, to a string, that must be a number? What is it for, and what do you enter? Edit: code has now been commented out.

Comment: @WeatherVane that part is commented it just didn't reflect here for some reason but I edited it so it's commented now.

Comment: The procedure is basically using a continual loop and force the user to enter the correct values, e.g. `while (1) { printf("\nEnter three side of a triangle:\n"); if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) break; fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar(); }` That way you force the user to enter what you want or you throw and error, clear the bad input and make him do it again....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ohh thanks a lot man! it worked!